# jQuery Ajax Show Value On Each TD Click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a small table with jQuery inside.
The TDs from *See Habs* column I wonder to show the each value based on their TD line.

With my current code, the button from each TD are still showing the value of first TD only and not showing up each TD when clicked.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1px">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Habitation</th>
      <th>See Hab</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Human</td> 
      <td>        
        <input type="hidden" id="habs" name="hab_name" value="Human">
        <button class="check">Check</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Animal</td> 
      <td>        
        <input type="hidden" id="habs" name="hab_name" value="Animal">
        <button class="check">Check</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Forest</td> 
      <td>        
        <input type="hidden" id="habs" name="hab_name" value="Forest">
        <button class="check">Check</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div id="resulthabs" style="background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;"></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $('.check').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'gethabs.php',
      data: $('#habs'),
      success: function(data){
        $('#resulthabs').html(data);
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

gethabs.php

```
if($_POST['hab_name']){
 $hab_name = $_POST['hab_name'];
 echo $hab_name;
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't send value!!!
Edit `ajax` request like:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'gethabs.php',
  data:'hab_name='+$(this).parent().find('input').val(),
  success: function(data){
    $('#resulthabs').html(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: Well, that so nice very working and look easy. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
 data: {hab_name : $(this).closest('td').find('#habs').val()},
```